# Getting Value Picker and HughesConnect Viewpicker combination in XPages

Tags: xpages

I have an application that uses the Ext Lib value picker from a view and it works but it is very cludgy.  The reason is that there are over a thousand choices and the user has to scroll through them all to get to where he/she wants to go.  I want to use the HughesConnect.com picklist CC, which is very nice.  However, I am having trouble with a particular issue that is probably very simple but I can't figure it out.

I want to be able to use the HughesConnect.com picklist CC to grab one value at a time and put it into a field.  Then, when the user clicks on the button again, I just want them to have the ability to grab a value and append it to the same field.  Every time I run it now, it is just overwriting the field.  I can't use Multi Value in the CC because the view has multi values in the column from the same document.  I have found that if this is the case, it doesn't work.  No matter what I try.  I am not very good with arrays in XPages, so I am likely doing something wrong and to be honest, I don't even have any sample code because everything I have tried hasn't worked.

I am starting to wonder whether it's even possible but it sounds so simple that it must be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Value Picker allows you to add a search with a view data source. Is there a reason for not using that? I can't remember if search support multi-select. It may not.

If you want to use Mark's view picker, how about getting a bit creative. Push the value into a Hidden Input field that has an onChange event. In the onChange event, append the value to a different multi-value field. If you bind the Dojo List Text Box to your multi-value field, it will make it easier for users to deselect entries. It's a bit creative, but should produce exactly the result you're looking for.

Comment: I don't see anything in the Value Picker properties that allows you to add a search with a domino view data source.  Can you point me to how to add the search with a view data source?  Thanks.

Comment: dojoType property needs setting to extlib.dijit.PickListSearch, p164 of XPages Extension Library book. There should be an example in Extension Library demo database.

Comment: Paul, thanks for the tip.  I had to use "extlib.dijit.PickerListSearch" (not sure if that was a typo or if it is a different dojoType property).  I also found your comment over here http://www.intec.co.uk/extension-library-value-picker-and-extlib-dijit-pickerlistsearch/ and it helped me to get the 1000 max row count to show in the picklist so thanks for that also.